# Prolog - program solve issue but backwards

Tags: prolog, graph-theory

```
edge(a,b).
edge(a,c).
edge(b,c).
edge(c,e).
edge(c,d).
edge(d,e).
edge(f,g).
edge(g,h).

allways(X,Y) :- edge(X,Z), allways(Z,Y), write(Z).
allways(X,Y) :- edge(X,Y), write(Y).
```

ways(a,e) is supposed to print all ways from a to e, this code solves the issue but print it out backwards.. any tips on how to make the program print the solutions out in correct ordet?

Output right now is:

```
ways(a,e).
edcb
true ;
ecb
true ;
edc
true ;
ec
true ;
false.
```

EDIT: Ive tried

```
allways(X,Y) :- edge(X,Z), write(Z), allways(Z,Y).
allways(X,Y) :- edge(X,Y), write(Y).
```

and the output got very weird, and I do not understand why.

```
?- allways(a,e).
bcedee
true ;
e
true ;
cedee
true ;
e
true ;
false.
```

Answer (score 0):

Change "write" predicate before allWays(), each time you wait with write to end your recursive function, so you're printing from end to start.

`allways(X,Y) :- edge(X,Z), write(Z), allways(Z,Y).
allways(X,Y) :- edge(X,Y), write(Y)`

Comment: It fixed the output backwards problem but instead the output gets really weird, haha..

Comment: @Frans, how much weird ?

Comment: Probably need to change order of `allways` functions, will check later.

Comment: I edited the post so you can see how weird it got! I tried but it did not do the job :/

Answer (score -1):

this is an old question, the reason i'm answering it is bco it's an repeating assignment for an computer science class, therefore I won't give the answer in code. 
You are checking if the nodes are connected using recursion, as you are starting at `(a and e)`, `(a and e)` will also return last *(after every other call within this call have returned)* 
here is what is happening *(in short pseudo-code)*:

```
a and e is checking
    base case fails
    a and b is connected
    b and e is checking
        base case fails
        b and c is connected
        c and e is checking
            base case sucess!
            write e
            return
        write c
        return
    write b
    return
    exit
```

the result are `ecb`, hence inverse of your expected `bce` 
now when we knowing what is happening, we can simply solve the problem by starting from the other end, if instead of cheking for a path from a to e, we can check for a path from e to a, doing so will get us the expected output.
Hope that helps!

***edited:***
a good idea in cases like this is to use the `trace` command.